# C# List binary or items together into one bitmask result

Tags: c#, linq, enums

I have a list of bit flags in c# in a list.  I would like to binary or them together to generate a bitmask.

For example a modifierKey enum that is treated as a bit field with the Flags attribute like so:

```
[Flags]
public enum ModifierKeys : uint
{
    Alt = 1,
    Control = 2,
    Shift = 4,
    Win = 8
}
```

I know I can do this with a for loop and just bitwise or the values together as uints and then cast back to the enum type.  My current working method looks like so:

```
public ModifierKeys ComputeMask(List<ModifierKeys> keys)
{
   uint value = 0;
   foreach(var item in keys)
   {
       value |= (uint)item;
   }

   return (ModifierKeys)value;
}
```

To my question - Can I do this be done with a single LINQ query or some other extension I am missing?

Comment: `Enumerable.Aggregate` is what you are looking for... Also it is questionable if you get more readable code as result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
uint value = keys.Aggregate<ModifierKeys, uint>(0, (current, item) => current | (uint)item);
```